# Cannot update attributes through = and save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following is the problem puzzling me:

I have a model Word, and it has an attribute article_count

however, if I use:

```
w = Word.first    
w.article_count = 1
w.save
```

the the first word's article_count will not change, the log shows:

```
Word Exists (0.4ms) ...
```

but I can use

```
w.update_attributes :article_count => 1
```

Maybe I misunderstood the function of save, can anyone explain to me?

======================= Update =======================

Here is my article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base   
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :source, :url

  has_many :article_wordships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :words, :through => :article_wordships
  has_many :paragraphs, :dependent => :destroy

  alias_attribute :word_count, :article_wordships_count

  validates_uniqueness_of :title
end
```

Here is my code:

```
Article.select(:title).all.each do |a|
  a.title = a.title.gsub(/\A.+?;\s(.+)/, '\1')
  a.save
end
```

And after run the code, nothing changes in the articles.

Here is the console info:

```
   1.9.3p194 :003 > a.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Article Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `articles` WHERE (`articles`.`title` = BINARY 'A Shared State of Defeat' AND `articles`.`id` != 178) LIMIT 1
   (0.9ms)  UPDATE `articles` SET `title` = 'A Shared State of Defeat', `updated_at` = '2012-09-08 02:58:33' WHERE `articles`.`id` = 178
   (2.2ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

Both save and save! return true.

Strangely, SOMETIMES IT WORKS, SOMETIMES IT DOES NOT WORK!

I'm getting mad...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean "SOMETIMES IT WORKS, SOMETIMES IT DOES NOT WORK!"  It seems to work in the example you give.  If by not work you mean it does not always issue updates, it might be that this line does not change the title.  ActiveRecord does dirty checking and if the value of title does not change, it will not issue an update.

```
a.title = a.title.gsub(/\A.+?;\s(.+)/, '\1')
```

Comment: I updated my post. Besides, I found the problem may lies in .select(:title)?